# Calculating the derived price for AMPL/ETH

Tags: chainlink

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the derived price from [the ChainLink docs example](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/#getting-a-different-price-denomination).

Here is my calculations based on code from the provided example:

```
    // AMPL/USD / ETH/USD = AMPL/ETH
    //
    // decimals: 18
    // baseDecimals (AMPL/USD): 18
    // quoteDecimals (ETH/USD): 8
    //
    // basePrice (AMPL/USD): 1042171653544521600
    // quotePrice (ETH/USD): 286133898282
    //
    // basePrice (AMPL/ETH scaled): 1042171653544521600
    // quotePrice (ETH/USD scaled): 286133898282 * 10^(18-8) =
    //                              2.861339e+21

    // AMPL/ETH (actual):  362708990937550
    // AMPL/ETH (derived): (104217165.354 * 10^18) / 2.861339e+21 =
    //                     36422.5159459
```

But the actual price is 0.0003673 ETH ([according to coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/ampleforth/ampl/eth/)).
The `latestRoundData` function from the [ChainLink AMPL/ETH price feed contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x492575FDD11a0fCf2C6C719867890a7648d526eB#readContract) returns 362708990937550.

[image]

Looks like I don't understand how the `scalePrice` function works. How do I calculate the correct derived price for AMPL/ETH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vasiliy-yorkin

The [ChainLink docs example](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/#getting-a-different-price-denomination) transform the values in order to have 18 decimal places.

The `latestRoundData` function from the ChainLink AMPL/ETH price feed contract returns the value in wei.

362708990937550 wei = 0.00036270899093755 ETH